# How to export artboards to PDF sorted by artboard name

Tags: sketchapp

In Sketch 56, how can I `Export Artboards to PDF` sorted by artboard name?

I've manually sorted the artboards in the sidebar, but that didn't do anything. Exporting to PDF seems to follow the order the artboards are visually placed on screen (from top left to bottom right).

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple artboards to export in one pdf with artboard name on each artboard.

Here is the thing you can do on sketchApp:
1.) Firstly give names to all artboards above them manually with Text field. Check out the attachment for more clarification.

2.) Multiple ways to use Slice function in SketchApp, you can simply press "S" and slice will activate and another way is clicking on insert button on top left corner you can select Slice from the list.

3.) Using slice you can slice all the artboards at one like you are taking a screenshot of all the artboards at once.

4.) Slice has an export function so you can select the format(jpg,pdf,png,etc.) how you want to export the slice selected by you.

5.) You can also change background color before exporting the slice, also you can rename that slice like we do for all artboards.

Hope I understood your question correctly and this answer helps you. if you still have confusion you can reply to comments.

Thanks
[SketchApp screen for slice function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIMlM.png)
[multiple artboard exported image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bxvv.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I just have the same problem and I was looking for plugins and to fix this you just have to go to the Sketch Preferences, actually your question makes me realize how Sketch export to PDF, I haven't noticed that exports from the right to the left and then from top to bottom.

So go to Preferences, click on Layers and under Artboard Export choose: "From the Layer list" > "Top to bottom".

Done